# Laptop always suspends when lid is closed

Tags: gnome, xfce, 13.10

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 Beta1 and my laptop now always suspends when the lid is closed, regardless of whether its on battery power or plugged in. I've double checked in power settings, tweak tool, dconf and xfce-power-manager (I have XFCE installed along side) and have tried setting it to 'do nothing', 'blank' and even 'power off' and yet it still suspends.

Answer (score 0):

Could be this bug or a new one : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1180513